# postgresql one column 2 opposite criteria

Tags: postgresql

In my data set, I am looking for value that have both positive and negative result under the amount category. For example, one entity can be bank account, and there are money coming in (positive number) and money going out (negative number).

```
SELECT description, account_subtype_id, subcategory_id, (case when amount > 0 then 1 end) AS amount_p, (case when amount < 0 then 0 end) AS amount_n
FROM mx.transactions
LIMIT 100
;
```

This approach doesn't help much because now my data looks like:

```
bank_A 1 null
bank_A null 0
```

But I really want to get something like:

```
bank_A 1 0
```

because this will be really helpful for my analysis.

Actually. If there is a way to do this, it would be even better:

For example, an entity has

```
Bank_A $500 -$300 -- (these two results both are from the amount column)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just one row per `description`, you need to `group by description` and use aggregate functions. A clean way to check whether there's any positive or negative `amount` would be to check whether `min(amount)` and `max(amount)` are less/greater than 0:

```
SELECT
  description,
  min(amount) < 0 AS amount_n,
  max(amount) > 0 AS amount_p
FROM mx.transactions
GROUP BY description
```

These tests will give you true and false values, but you can use them in your `CASE`/`IF` statements if you want something else. Or to get the actual values rather than testing against 0, just use `min` and `max` directly.

It looks like you've got multiple columns potentially acting as your `bank_A` identifier. If that's the case, you can `GROUP BY` all of them.

```
SELECT
  description,
  account_subtype_id,
  subcategory_id,
  min(amount),
  max(amount)
FROM mx.transactions
GROUP BY description, account_subtype_id, subcategory_id
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need. you are really really helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: sorry. one more follow-up question. So I am also interested in whether this amount is divisible by 100 (because this is another unique feature for this sample data along with having both positive and negative values. So I add another line in **SELECT** `amount % 100 = 0 AS amount_i` and change the **GROUP BY** to `GROUP BY description, amount`. It seems that my database is too big (about 10m+ rows), and this query is running forever. is there a way to solve this?

Comment: never mind! it took about 30 mins to run, but it works. thank you so much! XD